# trying to fix possibly a memory issue?

Tags: c, matrix

I'm running a 4x4 matrix in my code. Sometimes I get the correct answer, sometimes I get some of the right solution and the rest is weird numbers. For instance, my matrices are both

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

My solution should be

```
10 20 30 40
10 20 30 40
10 20 30 40
10 20 30 40
```

but sometimes I get

```
10 20 30 40
10 20 30 40
10 20 20 20
10 20 30 40
```

I believe I have a memory problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. I have tried deallocating memory but it didn't change anything, however, I could have put it in the wrong place.

Heres my code

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <pthread.h>

   //Create a typedef to pass vectors into the dot product
   typedef struct {
     int L;
     float *v1;
     float *v2;
  } dotVectors;



  //Prototype for the readMatrix method
  float** readMatrix(int *nRows, int *nCols,FILE* f);

  //Threaded dot product
  void* pDotProduct(void *p){
     //Recast the void pointer to a dotVectors pointer
     dotVectors *p1 = (dotVectors*) p;


     //Get all the stuff where the pointer is pointing
     int L = p1->L;
     float *v1 = p1->v1;
     float *v2 = p1->v2;

     float *sum = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));

      //Do the dot product
      *sum=0;
      int i; for(i=0;i<L;i++){


         *sum+=v1[i]*v2[i];

     } free(v2);
      //Return the sum
      pthread_exit((void*)sum);


  }


  //Creates an empty matrix with r rows and c columns
  float** createFloatMatrix(int r, int c) {
    float** newMatrix =(float**)malloc(r*sizeof(float*));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<c; i++) newMatrix[i]=(float*)malloc(c*sizeof(float));
    return newMatrix;
  }


  //Initializes a matrix with "value"
  void initMatrix(float **M, int r, int c, float value){
     int i,j;
     for (i=0; i<r; i++)
       for(j=0; j<c; j++)
          M[i][j]=value;
  }


  //Prints out a matrix with r rows and c columns
  void printMatrix(float** m, int r, int c) {
      int i,j;
     for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0; j<c; j++){ printf("%g ", m[i][j]);}
        printf("\n");}

  }

  main() {
    float  **m1,**m2;
    int i,j,r1,c1,r2,c2;

    //Read in the first matrix from a file M1
    FILE* f;
    f=fopen("m1","r");

    //Reads the matrices from standard input - one file at a time
    m1 = readMatrix(&r1,&c1,f);
    fclose(f);


    //Read in a second matrix from a file M2
    f=fopen("m2","r");
    m2 = readMatrix(&r2,&c2,f);
    fclose(f);

    //*************//
    pthread_t t[r1][c2];

    //****************//
   //Create a dotVectors and fill it in
   int cr=c1; int rc; int k;

  for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
         for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
                 dotVectors *d= (dotVectors*)malloc(sizeof(dotVectors));
                 //Create a vector to store the jth column of the second matrix
                 float* temp = (float*)malloc(cr*sizeof(float));

                 for(k=0; k<cr; k++){ temp[k]=m2[k][j];}


                 d->L=c1;
                 d->v1=m1[i];
                 d->v2=temp;
                 rc = pthread_create(&t[i][j],NULL,pDotProduct,(void*)d);
                 }
         }

   //****************//
   void* dp;
   float** result=createFloatMatrix(r1,c2);
   //initMatrix(result, r1, c2, 0);
   for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
         for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
                 pthread_join(t[i][j],&dp);
                 result[i][j] = *((float*)dp);


                 }
         }printMatrix(result, r1,c2);
         pthread_exit(NULL);
         }

 //Read a matrix from a file f
   float** readMatrix(int *nRows, int *nCols, FILE* f) {
   int i=0;
   int j=0;
   int k=0;
   char c;
   *nRows=1; //The number of rows
   *nCols=1; //The number of columns
   float  nums[30][30];
   char* num;

   while(1) {

     //Read in the numbers on a row
     j=0; // j = the index of the number on the row - start at zero
     while(1) {

       //We will re-use the index i, so set to zero
       i=0;

       num = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));

       //Read characters from standard input until a space or EOL
       while((c=getc(f))!=' ' && c!=10 && c!=EOF ) {
         num[i++]=c;
       }

       //Null terminate the array of characters
       num[i]=0;

       //Changes the array of characters to a float
       nums[k][j++]=atof(num);

       //If we are at the end of the line or end of file - break
        if( c==10 || c==EOF) break;

       //Set the number of numbers
       (*nCols)=j+1;
     }

     //Stop if you are at the end of file
     if (c==EOF) break;

     //Go to the next row
     k++;

    } //End while(1) outer loop
    *nRows=k;

    //Allocate memory for the row pointers
    float** retMat = (float**)malloc((*nRows)*sizeof(float*));
    //Allocate memory for the rows themselves
    for(i=0; i<(*nRows); i++) retMat[i]=(float*)malloc((*nCols)*sizeof(float));
    //Copy the nums matrix into the return matrix
    for(i=0; i<(*nRows); i++) for(j=0; j<(*nCols); j++) retMat[i][j]=nums[i][j];
    return retMat;
```

If I run through the debugger twenty or so times I get a segmentation fault that says it's in `pthread_join ()`. But I do not see how it could be. Does anyone have any advice or help on this issue?

Comment: Consider getting rid of those line numbers. Makes it difficult for anyone to try your code. Also: Consider stating up front: What is your program supposed to do?

Comment: What exactly are you using 'rc' for? It's only assigned to. And do you mean you have two 4x4 matrices and you want to take the **cross** product of them? Because the **dot** product yields a scalar, not a vector.

Comment: Should this be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @TomBarron Probably not since it's giving incorrect results, but I could be wrong.

Comment: My code is supposed to take the first row of the first matrix and multiply it by the first column of the second matrix. rc is supposed to get the thread going.

Comment: ..Where are your line 33-35?

Comment: it was blank space that I didnt copy over

Comment: Just ran it over 500 times on my mac with no errors. "My code is supposed to take the first row of the first matrix and multiply it by the first column of the second matrix." Wouldn't that just put out a single row? It looks to me like to does r1*c1, r2*c2, r3*c3, r4*c4, producing four rows

Comment: What machine/OS are you using?

Comment: That is correct it supposed to multiply the rows from the first matrix by the column of the second row but Im not understanding how its not working for me. Something is not right somewhere. Im running it off of putty connected to a server at school and I cant remember the OS. I know someone that ran similar code and it worked on his server but when transferred to the teachers it through some segmentation faults every once in a while.

Comment: is it possible that I am running out of memory on my spot of the server?

Comment: My suggestions would be: 1) get it working without threading, 2) simplify it as much as you can -- e.g., why does readMatrix need to create a matrix of pointers to the values? Why not just a matrix of float values? 3) bring it up to date -- atof() has been superceded by strtod(), etc. 4) add threading back in if you need it.

Comment: What seems more likely to me is that when you get the third row in the output being 10 20 20 20 it's because somehow the third and fourth pointers in that row of the input matrix got pointed at the wrong value -- the 2 rather than the 3 and 4. That's why I think it would be helpful to you to simplify down to just a matrix of floats rather than a matrix of pointers to floats.

As far as the segmentation faults, I don't know. I would suspect a stray pointer at something illegal rather than an out of memory issue. If you ran out of memory, you'd see malloc failures.

Comment: In `readMatrix` consider checking that `i`, `j`, `k` do not overflow bounds, and check results of `malloc` and `fopen`

Answer (score 1):

I just compiled this (missing a `}` at the end of your listing) with `gcc -g -lpthread`, then ran the resulting executable through `valgrind`. It generated lots of errors (memory allocated but not freed) but no segmentation faults - and the output was correct.

I definitely recommend getting this to work properly without threading first. You want to re-think your memory allocation strategy. For example, you can create a block of memory all at once, then create an array of pointers to it. This is what `Numerical Recipes in C` does - it allows you to "fake" a variable length 2D matrix.  For each `create` you need a `free` as well. And make sure you keep track of rows vs columns. In your original code for creating an `rxc` matrix, you actually created `cxc` space - so if you had called it with `r>c` you would have had a segmentation fault just from that...

Example of doing this "better":

```
float** createFloatMatrix(int r, int c) {
  float** newMatrix =(float**)malloc(r*sizeof(float*));
  newMatrix[0] = malloc(r*c*sizeof (float) );
  for(i=1; i<r; i++) newMatrix[i]=newMatrix[0] + i*c;
  return newMatrix;
}
```

And the corresponding

```
void freeFloatMatrix(float** m) {
  free(m[0]); // this frees the whole block
  free(m);    // this frees the array of pointers
}
```

Of course your `readMatrix` function is doing some horrible things - it is assuming that the input matrix cannot be larger than 30x30 but doesn't test to make sure that it stays in bounds; when you create a return matrix you don't use your own `createFloatMatrix` function, ...

Finally - it seems like you are doing matrix multiplication in an incredibly complex way. The following would appear to do the same thing, but in fewer lines. Is there a reason why you don't do it this way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Prototypes
float** readMatrix(int *nRows, int *nCols,FILE* f);
void freeFloatMatrix(float**);

//Prints out a matrix with r rows and c columns
void printMatrix(float** m, int r, int c) {
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
    for(j=0; j<c; j++) { 
      printf("%g ", m[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

// rewritten function for allocating float matrix:
float** createFloatMatrix(int r, int c) {
  int i;
  float** newMatrix =(float**)malloc(r*sizeof(float*));
  newMatrix[0] = malloc(r*c*sizeof (float) );
  for(i=1; i<r; i++) newMatrix[i]=newMatrix[0] + i*c;
  return newMatrix;
}

// need a function to free the matrix!!
void freeFloatMatrix(float** m) {
  free(m[0]); // this frees the whole block
  free(m);    // this frees the array of pointers
}


int main(void) {  // <<<< let's get the signature right...
float  **m1,**m2;
int i,j,r1,c1,r2,c2;

//Read in the first matrix from a file M1
FILE* f;
f=fopen("m1","r");
m1 = readMatrix(&r1,&c1,f);
fclose(f);

//Read in a second matrix from a file M2
f=fopen("m2","r");
m2 = readMatrix(&r2,&c2,f);
fclose(f);

// make sure that the dimensions match up:
if(c1 == r2) {
  float temp, **m3;
  int ii, jj, kk;
  m3 = createFloatMatrix(r1, c2);
  for(ii = 0; ii < r1; ii++) {
    for(jj = 0; jj < c2; jj++) {
      temp = 0;
      for(kk = 0; kk < c1; kk++) {
        temp += m1[ii][kk] * m2[kk][jj];
      }
      m3[ii][jj] = temp;
    }
  }
  printf("The product of the matrices is:\n");
  printMatrix(m3, r1, c2);
  freeFloatMatrix(m3);
  }
else printf("dimensions don't match!\n");
freeFloatMatrix(m2);
freeFloatMatrix(m1);
return 0;
}

//Read a matrix from a file f
float** readMatrix(int *nRows, int *nCols, FILE* f) {
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  int k=0;
  char c;
  *nRows=1; //The number of rows
  *nCols=1; //The number of columns
  float  nums[30][30];
  char num[10];

 while(1) {
 //Read in the numbers on a row
   j=0; // j = the index of the number on the row - start at zero
   while(1) {
   //We will re-use the index i, so set to zero
     i=0;

     //Read characters from standard input until a space or EOL
     while((c=getc(f))!=' ' && c!=10 && c!=EOF && i < 10) {
       num[i++]=c;
     }

     //Null terminate the array of characters
     num[i]=0;

     //Changes the array of characters to a float
     nums[k][j++]=atof(num);

     //If we are at the end of the line or end of file - break
     if( c==10 || c==EOF || j == 30) break;

     //Set the number of numbers
     (*nCols)=j+1;
   }

   //Stop if you are at the end of file
   if (c==EOF) break;

   //Go to the next row
   k++;
   if (k == 30) break;
  } //End while(1) outer loop
  *nRows=k;

  //Allocate memory for the row pointers using the function we defined before
  float** retMat = createFloatMatrix(*nRows, *nCols);
  return retMat;
}
```

Note - there are plenty of other places where this code can be improved... but at least the above will do an OK job of matrix multiplication when you have well conditioned inputs which do not exceed the size you assumed in your code.

Once you convince yourself that this works you could consider adding threading at some level - assuming that your assignment includes making this code multi-threaded. My personal approach would be to `#include <omp.h>` and just add `#pragma omp for` in the appropriate place, but then I'm lazy when it comes to multi-threading.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice I greatly appreciate the advice